# tcolorbox \newtcbtheorem "label separator" option

Tags: tcolorbox

I use tcolorbox to definie new theorem styles. This is one example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{remarq}{Remarque}{%
    breakable,enhanced,colback=blue!10!white,%
    colframe=blue!95!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,%
    label separator={' :'}}{remarq}
\newenvironment{remarque}{\begin{remarq*}}{\end{remarq*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{remarque}{}{}
  Une remarque...
\end{remarque}
\end{document}
```

I can't seem to find the correct way to signify I would like a space before my ":" in the heading of the theorem : "Remarque :" and not "Remarque:" (as you may guess, I'm french :)

Can anyone help me on this matter ? The manual is not very specific on this matter (or, more certainly, I read it wrong...).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `separator sign` and not `label separator`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{remarq}{Remarque}{%
    breakable,enhanced,colback=blue!10!white,%
    colframe=blue!95!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,%
    separator sign={\ :}}{remarq}
\newenvironment{remarque}{\begin{remarq*}}{\end{remarq*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{remarque}{test}{}
  Une remarque...
\end{remarque}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes ! My mistake. I confused the label written in the title and the label written in reference on page 339 : flashed on ":", didn't read the rest :-( Thanks a lot.